# How to start OSGi bundle in different port in karaf with jetty

Tags: jetty, osgi, apache-karaf, osgi-bundle, pax-web

I have multiple **OSGi bundles** and would like to expose those bundles from different port. Basically bundles has **REST API** and I would like to run API's in different ports.

My REST API bundle jars is having jaxrs:server configuration.

```
 <jaxrs:server id="services" address="/logger">

 </jaxrs:server>
```

I can start the multiple connectors with configuration provided below.

```
 <Call name="addConnector">
    <Arg>
        <New class="org.eclipse.jetty.server.nio.SelectChannelConnector">
            <Set name="host">
                <Property name="jetty.host" />
            </Set>
            <Set name="port">
                <Property name="jetty.port" default="8282" />
            </Set>
            <Set name="maxIdleTime">300000</Set>
            <Set name="Acceptors">2</Set>
            <Set name="statsOn">false</Set>
            <Set name="confidentialPort">8443</Set>
            <Set name="lowResourcesConnections">20000</Set>
            <Set name="lowResourcesMaxIdleTime">5000</Set>
            <Set name="name">jettyConn2</Set>
        </New>
    </Arg>
</Call>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as long as your jaxrs is served by different servlets, which are configured in different web application bundles (WABs). 
You need to make sure all of your application bundles contain the required Headers:

```
WebContext-Path: /logger
Web-Connectors: jettyConn2
```

Unless your jaxrs framework has a central servlet that registers with its own WebContext-Path this should work for you.

Comment: Thanks. This resolved my issue. But now the problem is service is accessable from both URL'S. For example /cxf/logger and /logger/logger. Because cxf is default servlet which we cannot remove i guess. How to change the configuration to access only from one URL?

Comment: check the documentation for CXF, it's possible to switch to another path for it.